# adding HTML with Javascript, want to know when it is done loading

Tags: javascript, html

I am loading some HTML with Javascript, when that is done, I want to load some other script that makes use of the just loaded HTML. When I run both at the same time, there is a good change that the HTML is not ready before the Javascript, and so gives an error. The injected HMTL and JavaScript are created by someone else. And due to numbers, it's not feasible to do it by hand.

The reason I cannot use window.onload or others like it is that parts of the Page get replaced from the JS. Usually I just load the new stuff and then when the user interacts with it go to the next part.

Is this the right way to make sure the **new** HTML is done loading and then loading the new Javascript?

```
var rowDiv = document.createElement( "div" );
rowDiv.className = "row info-row";
rowDiv.addEventListener("load", addMoreJS(); );
// Add more HTML things
// Bring it All together.
domelement.appendChild( rowDiv );
```

*if this question is not new and has a good answer, please point to it*

Comment: That javascript is synchonous, so the last line will always run after the previous lines (unless your use async calls, timeouts, etc.). That said what's your definition of "loaded"? This question isn't very clear TBH and needs more details

Comment: For this you can load script dynamically on body load event which will help you to load second script using html. e.x. <body onload="script();">

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to change ->

```
rowDiv.addEventListener("load", addMoreJS(); );
```

To something like ->

```
rowDiv.addEventListener("load", addMoreJS);
```

Otherwise addMoreJS is getting executed before the load event even fires.

Comment: ↑ this. aswell as some good advice: event listeners simply execute callbacks. the second argument takes a function or a eval expression. executing a function does not return a function but what ever that function is made to return (and yes it could even return a function but if it does, i'd imply you already know what i'm talking about).

Comment: Yes, this works. Not quite used to functions as arguments.